# How to use brotli compression in a create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, compression, create-react-app, brotli

I want to use brotli compression in my project created using 'create-react-app', but for that how do I make changes in the webpack.config.js file?
I don't want to eject the config files as that could break my project.
Also I'm unable to understand how this can be done via @craco/craco library, if that is the only option through which we can make this change.